# Struggling to plot a normal curve (gaussian curve) on a histogram in r

Tags: r, histogram, curve-fitting, gaussian, curve

I want to plot a histogram of a dataframe I have, which works with my code. However I'm trying to attach a normal curve to the graph. I attached the code and to clarify, exp_data is a three column data frame with index, ori_0 and ori_90. I attached the problem and my code, I appreciate any help anyone can offer. I have dplyr, ggplot2, and a few other things installed.

I tried to use the curve and dnorm functions to make a normal curve but it wouldn't come through.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a toy example:

```r
# create some sample data
x <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
# plot the histogram (you can use data from your data.frame here)
hist(x, probability = TRUE)
# add normal density curve to histogram
lines(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.1), 
      y = dnorm(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.1), mean = 0, sd = 1), 
      lwd = 2, 
      col = 'blue')
```

[image: histogram with normal density curve]

Comment: in this line of code:
lines(seq(-3, 3, 0.1), dnorm(seq(-3, 3, 0.1), 0, 1), lwd = 2, col = 'blue') what does the 0,1 at the end of the dnorm function mean, that is the mean and standard deviation values right?

Comment: Correct @Cameron Renaud, I will edit the code to clearly indicate what parameters are!